# Why does this canvas code not work?

Tags: canvas, khan-academy

I have been playing about with the random number generator on the Khan academy website. This is the code that I have entered into the console. I know that there is no ctx stuff there but the code is very similar to working with a normal HTML canvas. I am trying to get the canvas to show a bar chart of cumulative frequency, showing how many times the random number generator has picked each number. To do this I am trying to take the total amount of times that each number has come up, and then use that as the variable for the height of each bar in the chart.

```
    var num_1 = 0;
    var num_2 = 0;
    var num_3 = 0;
    var num_4 = 0;
    var num_5 = 0;
    var num_6 = 0;
    var num_7 = 0;
    var num_8 = 0;
    var num_9 = 0;
    var num_10 = 0;

    var draw = function() {      //the draw function just repeats the stuff inside it every second
    var random_num = random(0,10);

    if(random_num === 1){
        num_1 = num_1 + 1;
    }else if(random_num === 2){
        num_2 = num_2 + 1;
    }else if(random_num === 3){
        num_3 = num_3 + 1;
    }else if(random_num === 4){
        num_4 = num_4 + 1;
    }else if(random_num === 5){
        num_5 = num_5 + 1;
    }else if(random_num === 6){
        num_6 = num_6 + 1;
    }else if(random_num === 7){
        num_7 = num_7 + 1;
    }else if(random_num === 8){
        num_8 = num_8 + 1;
    }else if(random_num === 9){
        num_9 = num_9 + 1;
    }else if(random_num === 10){
        num_10 = num_10 + 1;
    }
    fill(122, 116, 116);
    rect(height, width/10, 20, num_1);
    rect(height, width/9, 20, num_2);
    rect(height, width/8, 20, num_3);
    rect(height, width/7, 20, num_4);
    rect(height, width/6, 20, num_5);
    rect(height, width/5, 20, num_6);
    rect(height, width/4, 20, num_7);
    rect(height, width/3, 20, num_8);
    rect(height, width/2, 20, num_9);
    rect(height, width/1, 20, num_10);
 };
```

Comment: What's supposed to be happening? What's actually happening? Your problem isn't clear.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I have added a little more now.

Comment: please refactor this code using nums=[0,0,0,0,0,...]; then later nums[random_num]+=1; then a for loop on i { rect (h,w/i, 20, (10-i)) }

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite simple.  You have your if statements react if the random number *exactly equals* a whole number. The random function chooses a random number *with a decimal*.  There are two very easy ways to solve this.

1) Have

```
random_num = round(random(0,10));
```

or

2) Use > and < signs in your if statements.  ex:
make sure you start with "> 2", if you don't already know.

```
var random_num = random(1, 11)
```

-skipping some code here-

```
if (random_num < 2) {(too lazy to copy code in here)}  
else if (random_num < 3) {(again)}  
*ect.*
```

I personally find the first o be the easiest.